# Converting untagged corpora to tagged (NLTK)

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have a plaintext corpora, that I want to tag and save, so I can use it further. What's the best way to do this?

I already have my tagger made, but I can't figure out a way to change the corpora that isn't messy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at other tagged corpora, like brown, for output examples. This will give you an idea of what a tagged corpus should look like. Next, load your corpus (with the `PlaintextCorpusReader`) and iterate over the sentences, tagging each sentence. Then write each tagged sentence to a file by making a string from the tagged sentence, as in `' '.join([tuple2str(t) for t in tagged_sent])` (after you do `from nltk.tag.util import tuple2str`). And it's ok if your code is "messy" as long it does the job correctly. You're not looking for an elegant algorithm here, you're running a very specific script to create a custom corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing simple unigram tagging, or are you actually parsing the text?  I believe NLTK parses/tags such that the output of every token is (token, PoS).  Is an array of tuples unacceptable for storing your corpora?  Why do you find this messy?